# Кто уже попробовал IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.0.4. Стоит уходить с Eclipse?

Tags: android, ide, eclipse, intellij-idea

Скачал вот, поставил, еле сообразил как дроидный проект запустить. Упёрлась рогами и всё: нету говорит у меня JDK и всё тут. А два SDK ставть не даёт. Пришлось пустой создать, потом добавлять всё... теперь работает.
Т.е. прямо с ходу грабли. Потом посидел порылся в настройках, поменял GUI на тёмный, что приятно порадовало, потому собрал тестовый проектик - работает. Не вероятно, но даже эмуляторы быстрее запускаются.
Короче, я в раздумьях. Стоит ли?

Тем, кто не в курсе, фирма JetBrains выпустила фришную версию своего редактора IntelliJ IDEA, я ещё не разобрался в чём там разница с Ultimate, но уже сейчас вижу: мне этого достаточно, что в Community Edition есть.

Редактор форм - положил эклипсловский на лопатки (ИМХО). Но вот работа не с лаерами, а всякими другими типами XML меня удручила, если чесно я уже отвык локализировать программы осторожничая с форматированием XML, пользуюсь встроенным редактором эклипса.

Comment: использовал идею более года. Впечатления самые положительные. А комбинация `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+N` перекрывает все плюсы эклипса. (это такая комбинация, которая показывает список всех доступных сущностей в коде - имена классов, переменных, полей, имен файлов и дает возможность быстро найти  нужное, даже если помнишь две-три буквы имени).

Answer (score 4):

Ещё как стоит. IDEA на порядок круче Eclipse и Netbeans вместе взятых. Заметно быстрее, более интеллектуальный code completion (который работает даже в XML-ках) и поиск (в том числе и нечёткий), куча автоматических инспекций кода, показывающих потенциальные ошибки и возможные оптимизации, нереально крутые возможности рефакторинга. Вообще, IDEA отличается от других IDE чётким пониманием контекста, в котором работает программист, и, следовательно более осмысленными действиями, направленными  на то, чтобы ему помочь и ускорить разработку. Если 12 не устраивает своей стабильностью, то попробуйте 11, она должна быть стабильнее.

Comment: а в ней можно создать jar файл с вложенными jar файлами ?

Comment: все что угодно...

Comment: @sonniy, прикручиваете maven/ant и крутите по вкусу. Интеграция достаточно хорошая.

Comment: Конечно, можно. Project settings -> Arifacts -> Add  -> Jar. После этого можно добавлять любые файлы и папки в выходной артефакт. После сохранения жмём Build -> Build artifacts -> [имя артефакта] -> Build. А вообще, поддержка Ant'а позволяет ещё и не такие извращения проделывать.

Answer (score 1):

Стоит, еще как стоит... Eclipse по сравнению с IDEA это как "Москвич" против "Мерседеса"

11-я версия стабильнее.

Но надо быть морально готовым, к тому что нововведения по разработке под Android будут слегка запаздывать на пару-тройку месяцев. Все таки Eclipse родная среда разработки для Android.

Comment: А можно расписать коротко алгоритм импорта проектов из Excon?
Что нужно и чего не нужно? А то я пару импортнул и сравнив с родным Идеевским наблюдаю там лишнее, но не в курсе -  нужно ли оно?

Answer (score 0):

Уходите, и даже не задумывайтесь. Уже пол года работаю с Intelij IDEA, Eclipse вспоминаю как страшный сон. К тому же, делаю пару совместных проектов под Android. Так, меня просят очень часто пересобрать или перекомпилировать что-то, птому то Eclipse не может этого сделать.
Переходите, не пожалеете.